# Some confusion about the traffic of github repo?

Tags: github

As the pictures show below, the `git clones` of my repo is 26, and the `visitor` of my repo is 4. According to the literal meaning, the `cloners` means who look my repo page and decide to clone my repo to local or somewhere, and also, in the meantime, they should become the `visitors` of my repo. However, the traffic data of my repo shows that the results of visitors and cloners are much different from each other.

My insight of visitor and coloner is right? What is the GitHub official definition of the cloners and visitors? Or, the significant difference that shows on my picture just caused by the bug of GitHub.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `git clone http://url` will clone the repo without visiting GitHub. Maybe your repo's name is an easy misspelling of another repo, or someone attempted to download all repos by cloning from a list of URLs, looking for loose passwords or doing statistical research.

It could be cloned by you from **another IP** (other home/TOR/VPN) or you told someone about the repo and someone cloned it **without visiting** the page.

> Do you have a CI/CD server or a DevOps pipeline?
>
> These will clone your repo automatically when triggered by a commit or
>   a pull request.

Comment: all right..., I remember that I deploy my repo on the travis-ci, so, each new commit will trigger a new **unique** clone of CI?

Comment: That is right! As far as I know and have searched for your issue, that should be the misunderstanding, but let me note that I am not working in GitHub of course.